# It is possible to store array value in database and using with where clause in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to store array type in a column in database and select it back using where to compare **n_group_code_id** between **array($gID)** 
as below function.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_notification` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `n_user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `n_group_code_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `n_source_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `n_activity_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `n_create_times` datetime NOT NULL,
  `n_description` varchar(160) NOT NULL,
  `n_status` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=542 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tb_notification`
--

INSERT INTO `tb_notification` (`id`, `n_user_id`, `n_group_code_id`, `n_source_id`, `n_activity_type`, `n_create_times`, `n_description`, `n_status`, `url`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) VALUES
(535, 66, '[7,11,11,11]', 1, 'Issue Till', '2016-04-25 07:04:54', 'Issue Till', 0, '0', '2016-04-25 07:59:54', '2016-04-25 07:59:54'),
(536, 66, '[7,11,11,11]', 1, 'Issue Till', '2016-04-25 08:04:47', 'Issue Till', 0, '0', '2016-04-25 08:15:47', '2016-04-25 08:15:47'),
(537, 66, '[7,11,11,11]', 159, 'Transfer till', '2016-04-25 08:04:45', 'Transfer till', 0, '0', '2016-04-25 08:20:45', '2016-04-25 08:20:45'),
(538, 66, '[7,11,11,11]', 160, 'Transfer till', '2016-04-25 09:04:04', 'Transfer till', 0, '0', '2016-04-25 09:06:04', '2016-04-25 09:06:04'),
(539, 66, '[7,11,11,11]', 1, 'Issue Till', '2016-04-26 07:04:29', 'Issue Till', 0, '0', '2016-04-26 07:35:29', '2016-04-26 07:35:29'),
(540, 66, '[7,11,11,11]', 162, 'Issue Till', '2016-04-26 07:04:32', 'Issue Till', 0, '0', '2016-04-26 07:38:32', '2016-04-26 07:38:32'),
(541, 69, '[7,11,11,11]', 163, 'return Till', '2016-04-26 08:04:33', 'return Till', 0, '0', '2016-04-26 08:39:33', '2016-04-26 08:39:33');
```

Here is my function:

```
 public function getNotification($user_id =null, $gId=null)
    {
            if(is_array($gId)) {

                $this->_data = self::select('*')
                    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'n_user_id')
                    ->where('users.id','=', $user_id)
                    ->whereIn('n_group_code_id',$gId)
                    ->get();
                if (count($this->_data)) {
                    return $this->_data;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }else {
                return false;
            }

    }
```

Comment: It depends on how your database will look like. If in one column only use `implode()` if not  then use `foreach()`

Comment: I insert data like this [7,11,11,11] format so is it possible in mysql or Laravel?

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible, but I'd recommend you to not reinvent the wheel and use [json](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations) type in DB and [encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) your array before saving and [decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it after loading from DB.

First of all, change your column type from string to json (click first link to find all info).

To save data:

```
$model = new Model();
....
$model->jsonData = json_encode($array);
$model->save();
```

To retrieve data:

```
$model = Model::find($id);
$array = json_decode($model->jsonData);
```

Also, you could do that automatically with using [accessors and mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: so when I insert it as Json how can I select with that data

Comment: Medzenin
How to used where clause because i want to select where with n_group_code_id with $gid look like n_group_code_id(7,11,11) = $gid(7,11,11)

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Can you please take a look on my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38826362/laravel-associate-method-is-returning-empty-array-in-the-view)